# How to rename using the CMD a folder opened in Explorer?

Tags: cmd.exe, rename

I need to rename through CMD a folder that has a subfolder open in Explorer.

```
Folder/         <= I need to rename this folder.
   Subfolder/   <= It is open in explorer.
   files...
```

But whenever I try this, the CMD throws the error below:

```
> REN Old New
Access denied.
```

After some tests, I understood that this error is thrown because the subfolder is open in the explorer. I would like to know how do I force the CMD to rename the folder.

Comment: You generally cannot rename or delete busy files / folders. Close first and then rename. Depending on where the folder is (say in Program Files), you may need to open cmd with Run as Administrator.

Comment: @John And how can I close only the open explorer in the subfolder?

Comment: @John Also, why can I move the folder from one directory to another without any problems?

Comment: Usually just close Explorer so that the file / folder is not busy. That is what I would do.

Comment: If a folder "handle" is in use, locking the folder, you can try a third-party tool such as Lock Hunter, https://lockhunter.com/ , to unlock it.

Comment: You can close Explorer, re-open it and then move the file. If the file is locked (you need to clarify by editing your question) you can use Unlocker or other tool to remove the locking handle. I have done this. Be sure to clarify your question.

Comment: Op, can you help us understand why you are having trouble closing explorer, or don't want to do it?

Comment: from cmd use `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer` - this will KILL ALL explorer windows and open a new one - necessary as explorer.exe is parent for the taskbar & co - the rename should work now if nothing else is having a lock on it....

Comment: @FrankThomas I would like to force CMD to rename the folder without having to close the explorer, just like in the MOVE command. In addition, it is possible to rename the folder through the "GUI" without having to close the explorer. But the solution to closing the explorer is fine. The problem is if there is more than one folder open. How could I close the correct explorer?

Comment: " I would like to force CMD to rename the folder without having to close the explorer, just like in the MOVE command"   You need to close Explorer so it is not running. You otherwise cannot force things.

Comment: If you need to, reboot the computer to get everything going properly.